# Why is reflection in a plane an automorphism?

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

I have not studied group theory, but would like to know in simple terms why reflection in a plane is an automorphism.
Dr. Hermann Weyl gives the definition of automorphism in his book 'symmetry' as

> A transformation which preserves the structure of space

What does he mean by the structure of space? Why can reflection preserve the structure?

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism) help? You can see that for example a reflection in a vector space along a subspace is compatible with vector addition. In general an automorphism only makes sense if you have described the structure of your object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase "structure of a space" has different meaning in different contexts.

The quote from Weyl probably gives the structure implicitly, and I am guessing that he is talking about planes in Euclidean 3-space. In that case, an automorphism is a bijection of the points of Euclidean 3-space which preserves all the structures of Euclidean geometry: lines; planes; distance; angle. In analytic geometry we learn a powerful theorem which says that any bijection of the points of Euclidean 3-space that preserves distance *also* preserves all the other structure: lines; planes; angle.

So Weyl's quote simply means that reflection across a plane preserves distance: using Cartesian coordinates $\mathbb{R}^3$ for Euclidean 3-space, with the usual distance formula $d(x,y)$ for points $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$, if $P \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is the plane and if $r : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is the reflection across $P$ then $d(r(x),r(y)) = d(x,y)$. This is pretty easy to prove using ordinary tools of analytic geometry: use a description of $P$ to write down a formula for $r$ and use that formula with coordinates for $x,y$ to prove $d(r(x),r(y))=d(x,y)$.

Comment: By saying 'we define the structure in the Helmholtz way, that would mean that it carries any two congruent figures into two congruent ones ', is Weyl talking about similarity in this context?Does congruence have other meanings back in his days?

Comment: No, congruence and similarity have the same meaning now as they did to Weyl all of 63 years ago, as they do in (translations of) Euclid who wrote 2300 years ago. Congruence means that distance --- the key structure of Euclidean geometry as explained in my answer --- is preserved. Similarity means distance is multiplied by a constant.

Answer (score 4):

The word *automorphism* can be used in a lot of contexts, as for example the sense here of a mapping of space (?) onto itself in a way that "preserves the structure".

This is a reference to the Euclidean properties of space, i.e. its distances and angles.  Reflection in any plane preserves the measures of distance and angles, and so is an automorphism in that sense.

Comment: It might be useful to add that the vector space structure is not preserved under reflection along a hyperplane unless it passes $0$. This makes clear that the definition is context-dependent since in both settings you can use $\mathbb R^n$ as the base space.

Comment: @AlexR : Thanks for this.  It's true that if we want to preserve vector space *structure*, then the plane of reflection needs to be a subspace, i.e. to pass through the origin.  But I didn't want to bring up those structures of space not preserved by reflection, as for example coordinates are not preserved.

Comment: given that it is Weyl writing, the reflection preserves the inner product; but more, if it is reflection in a root vector of an integral lattice, it preserves the lattice and lattice norm

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_group

I am pretty sure he is discussing, without using the terms, Lie Algebras and what came to be known as Weyl Chambers.

The setting for a root lattice is a (positive) quadratic form, let us call it $Q.$ The (squared) norm of a lattice vector $x$ is precisely $Q(x)$ which is an integer; for the cases of interest, this is usually going to be required to be a even integer, as the root lattices are "even."

The quadratic form gives rise to a symmetric **inner product**,
$$ \langle x,y \rangle = (1/2) \left( Q(x+y) - Q(x) - Q(y) \right).  $$
It is required that this be an integer when $x,y$ are in the lattice. This is the reason that norms must come out even, the whole business needs to be doubled to avoid half-integers.

Given an inner product, the reflection in a fixed vector $w$ is 
$$  z' = z - \frac{2 \langle z,w \rangle}{\langle w,w \rangle} w $$
You have seen this before, probably with ordinary dot product. Note that $w' = -w,$ but when $z$ is perpendicular to $w,$ then $z'=z.$

Next, given a even lattice, a **root** is a lattice vector $r$ such that $Q(r) = 2,$ or  $\langle r,r \rangle = 2$. It is because of this condition that reflection in $r$ becomes
$$ \color{magenta}{ z' = z -  \langle z,r \rangle r}  $$
Given any $z$ in the lattice, $z'$ is also in the lattice. This preserves the lattice and is called an automorphism. With positive $Q,$ the automorphism group is finite and is generated by the reflections.

Well, there is more to be said. I am now working in quadratic forms. I feel that if I had had a short course in quadratic forms, lattices, before Lie Algebras, it would have helped.

Enough for now

Comment: Does the book mention Lie algebras anywhere? Doesn't seem like it to me. For instance, lie, roots and weights are nowhere in the index, whereas "reflections" are discussed right in the first few pages (as the obvious geometric transformation of space).

Comment: @anon, probably not. A very complete treatment without Lie algebras is Humphreys, Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups.

Comment: @anon, I also recommend Lattices and Codes by W. Ebeling. I used, with permission, his description of Conway's trick for lattice automorphism groups, in a recent paper with Pete L. Clark. From the second edition, Section 4.5, Automorphism Groups.

Comment: Dr. Weyl's book [Symmetry (Princeton, 1952)](https://ia700809.us.archive.org/11/items/Symmetry_482/Weyl-Symmetry_text.pdf) is a popularizing work.  Quoting from the preface:  "This book is semi-popular in character.  It does not shun mathematics, but detailed treatment of most of the problems it deals with is beyond its scope."

Comment: @hardmath, alright. Anyway, here is a review of me: http://zmath.sub.uni-goettingen.de/ZMATH/msc/en/search/zmath/?q=an:06321119&type=pdf&format=complete